# React Native: onPress on component doesn't function

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs-flux

So I am using `react-native-router-flux` for my navigation in my ReactJS app but I am having difficulties using it with components.

For example the following code snippet works perfectly by pushing the next page when clicking the links.

```
export default class MainMenuPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Main Menu</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={Actions.bookmarksPage}>
          <Text>Bookmarks</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={Actions.settingsPage}>
          <Text>Settings</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

While the following code snippet nothing happens when you press the links.

```
export default class MainMenuPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Main Menu</Text>
        <MenuButton name="Bookmarks" onPress={Actions.bookmarksPage} />
        <MenuButton name="Settings" onPress={Actions.settingsPage} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class MenuButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Obviously the second code snippet is much more cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the `onPress` prop through to the `TouchableOpacity`:

```
class MenuButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```